# Android client custom login Azure Mobile service (.NET Back end)

Tags: android, azure, mobile

I have followed the steps in the following documentation http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/
 and built my .NET backend - I have been able to get the mobile service's new CustomRegistration and CustomLogin functions operational using the "try this out" button on the 
respective api pages at `localhost:<portNumber>/help/Api/POST-api-CustomLogin` and .`./CustomRegistration`. I have published these channges to the service to my azure mobile services.

I am then attempting to connect to the service using an android app that I am building in Android Studio. I am very new to Android and as a result I'm having difficulty getting my app to use
the CustomLogin provided by my mobile service. Below the code for the Android APP

In the java/com.example.howzit folder:

LoginResult.java

```
package com.example.howzit;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginResult {

    public String AuthenticationToken;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.LoginResultUser
    //     logged in.
    public LoginResultUser User;

}
```

LoginResultUser.java

```
package com.example.howzit;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginResultUser {
    public String UserId ;
}
```

LoginRequest.java

```
 package com.example.howzit;
    public class LoginRequest
    {
        public String username ;
        public String password ;
    }
```

In the TodoActivity class I have this:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://mysite.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "APIKEY",
                    this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter())
            .withFilter(new RefreshTokenCacheFilter());

        LoginRequest loginUser = new LoginRequest();
            loginUser.username = "theUserName";
            loginUser.password = "thePassword";

                mClient.invokeApi("CustomLogin",loginUser,LoginResult.class, new ApiOperationCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void  onCompleted(LoginResult result,Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse  response ){
                        if (error != null) {
                                    createAndShowDialog(error, "Error");
                                }
                                else {
                                    createAndShowDialog(result.User.UserId, "User");
                                }
                    }
                });
```

I have debugged this and it basically hits the invokeApi call and continues to load the rest
of the app never hitting the onCompleted routine...In Android Studio I have access to the LogCat, but there is nothing on there to inform me of an error. I'm really unable to get to the bottom of this. I have successfully implemented the Google login provider as well as the Window Azure 
provider, but am unable to with my own custom login. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

more info:. I have set up remote debugging on VS2013 and if I remove the authentication and debug, break points are hit when using the android app, but the when using the Authentication the CustomLogin Post in the Controller is never hit.

Comment: I have done custom login authentication with Windows Phone but not Android so I may be way off. When you connect to CustomLogin the login API is https://mysite.azure-mobile.net/api/CustomLogin. I know the tablecontrollers are all hit with /tables/.... Does the invoke api need api/CustomLogin? Or can you use Fiddler or something to see what URL its trying.

Comment: @Adam I have tried everything (with api/ and without) - cannot use fiddler because my debugging device is my android phone. Cannot use the emulator on my machine as it never loads up.- I've basically given up as I get no feedback from the adroid studio debugger to say what has gone wrong - extremely frustrating

Comment: Does it actually hit the API at the other end. E.g. putting a breakpoint on the CustomLogin method. The first point of call is to find out if it is even getting to the API and whether the error is connecting there or sending information back.

Comment: Just read the last little bit that the POST is never hit, so it is something wrong on the way there. Just getting more information, has the custom api got the anonymous security attribute on it? Also while you are at it, does adding something like this work: [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]
[Route("api/Account/CustomLogin")]
[HttpPost] Then calling api/Account/CustomLogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck at the same place here with Android+.NET+CustomAuthentication using the same tutorials.
The "Try this out" worked but the Android app won't.
I've tried Adam's answer but it didn't help.

After digging/poking around for hours, I used the Android debugger and kept going into SDK code till I found out there's a problem with JSON parsing to the LoginResult.class

com\google\gson\internal\bind\ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java

```
try {
    in.beginObject();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
      String name = in.nextName();
      BoundField field = boundFields.get(name);
      if (field == null || !field.deserialized) {
        in.skipValue();
      } else {
        field.read(in, instance);
      }
    }
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
  }
```

It seems that .NET serialization to JSON is different with Android on **initial** **letters**.

My working code pair following the tutorial,

.NET CustomLoginResult.cs

```
public class CustomLoginResult
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string MobileServiceAuthenticationToken { get; set; }

}
```

Android CustomLoginResult.java

```
public class CustomLoginResult {
    public String userId;
    public String mobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
}
```

Note the **initial letters** are different, the Java variable name must be **exactly** the same as the "try this out" result body.
[image]

Not sure if this solves the problem and Paul probably left/solved this problem long ago, but I hope this could help anyone stuck at the same place.

Comment: Jim - yes I found that the JSon and the property names on the class  were the issue...as you discuss above

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Adam's answer was very helpful!
However, instead of calling */api/Account/CustomLogin* you need to call **Account/CustomLogin/** .

`mClient.invokeApi("Account/CustomLogin/",...`

Then, the code should definitely be called in your backend. It may still be the case, that you don't get a return value back from the backend. To solve this problem, this question might help:

[Android and Azure Mobile Services: Using invokeAPI to return recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472205/android-and-azure-mobile-services-using-invokeapi-to-return-recordset)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this in an answer to be clearer even though not sure it is the correct answer.

Try putting

```
[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] 
[Route("api/Account/CustomLogin")] 
[HttpPost]
```

As attributes above your custom api controller method and then try calling /api/Account/CustomLogin

Comment: thanks I'll give this a try this evening. Just to let you know...if I use the test client (web interface) and send a customlogin request using the JSON in the interface then its all successful

Comment: Ok, then it looks like it is down to the SDK. Just to check, do you have the latest version of everything?

Comment: I have tried the above but no joy - thanks for the suggestion - I have downloaded everything in the last two weeks so I believe that every package is the latest